# calculating complexity for dynamic array reading

Tags: c, arrays, time-complexity

Does someone know what is the complexity of this function that reads a dynamic array of integers, and when there is not enough room for the next input, it double the array size and copies it into the new bigger array (address in the memory)?

how can I calculate it?

```
void readDynamicArray(int* arr, int& physicalSize, int& logicalSize)
{
    physicalSize=2;
    arr= new int[physicalSize];

    int tmpNum;
    logicalSize=0;
    cin>>tmpNum;

    while (tmpNum!=-1)// stop sign is -1, will help know when to stop reading into the array
    {
        if (logicalSize==physicalSize)
        {
            arr=newArrLoc(arr, physicalSize, logicalSize);
        }
        arr[logicalSize]=tmpNum;
        logicalSize++;
        cin>>tmpNum;
    }
}

int* newArrLoc(int* arr, int& physicalSize, int logicalSize)
{
    int* newArr=new int[physicalSize*=2];
    copyArray(newArr, arr, logicalSize);
    delete[] arr;   
    return newArr;
}

void copyArray (int arr[],int srcArr[] ,int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        arr[i]=srcArr[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The complexity is `O(number of elements)`.

Since you increase the size by a constant factor 2 in each iteration, at least half of the elements are copied at most once, a quarter at most twice, an eighth at most three times etc.

That means the total number of copied elements is bounded by

```
1/2 + 2/2^2 + 3/2^3 + 4/2^4 + ... = 2
```

times the total number of elements.

If you incremented by a constant factor `q`, the number of copies would be bounded by `q/(q-1)`, so that strategy always guarantees an `O(max{initial size, number of elements})` complexity. A factor of 2 gives a good compromise between few copies (the larger the growing factor `q` the fewer copies) and little space overhead (if you stop adding new elements immediately after the last resizing, you have `(q-1)*number_of_elements` space unused).

Comment: i'm really in doubt here, could you help me seeing where i went wrong in my logic? I mean, if he was adding one of space at a time, for each insertion (n), he'd have to copy the elements inserted (n - 1), having O(n^2) by the end of the process; then, wouldn't doubling the size reach a maximum of O(n logn)?

Comment: You failed to take into account that the amount of work needed for each copying (and allocation) grows exponentially. Say you get 2^n elements in total, and start with an array size of 1. First resizing allocates two cells and copies on. Second allocates four cells, copies two, so far 3 copies, 6 allocated cells. Third: 8 cells allocated, 4 copied, running sum 14 allocated, 7 copied. Fourth: 16 alloc, 8 copy, total 30 allocated, 15 copied, etc. You have `2^resizings - 1` copies, and allocate double that number of cells.

Comment: If you increment only by a fixed amount, the work necessary for each allocation grows only linearly, and that would indeed lead to an `O(n^2)` complexity.

Answer (score 0):

1. since your size of allocation doubles each time, if you read n elements, you did allocation lg(n) times.
2. at each allocation, you copied all element already read, i.e. n copies the last time, n/2 copies 2nd to the last, and so on. therefore, your total copies are Sum(2 + 2^2 + 2^3 + ... + n), there are lg(n) terms in it.
3. assume n is power of 2, and m = lg(n), then the sum is Sum(i from 0 to m) (2^i), which is bounded by 2^(m+1).
4. replace m by lg(n), that's 2^(lg(n) + lg(2)) = 2^(lg(2n)) = 2n, thus the complexity, in terms of how many copies you did, is O(n).